# SignalR between VsCode dev containers using default bridge network

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

If I create two ASP Core web services in VsCode and implement a SignalR hub in one which is connected to by the other (Dotnet 5, SignalR client library 5.11). This works fine. I can push these services up to Azure and it still works fine.

If however I open these webservices locally in a VsCode dev container and configure them to connect using the default Docker bridge network and the default forwarded port, I get a `Connection Refused` exception on the `HubConnection.StartAsync` call.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

I've tried a few things, using the http and https ports, disabling SSL verification in the client service but nothing works so far. I think I need some information on why this isn't working in the first place before I have much chance of coming up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that that Kestrel was still listening on the default network interface inside the Docker container and I needed to reconfigure it to listen on all interfaces for the connection to work.

So in `launchsettings.json` I needed to change `applicationUrl` from `"https://localhost:5003;http://localhost:5002"` to `"https://0.0.0.0:5003;http://0.0.0.0:5002"` and then everything worked pefectly.